# Reusing a variable that is based on multiple redux props without duplication of code

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to set a property based on multiple values from my redux store. (If it makes any difference I use [Rematch](https://rematchjs.org/) to handle my global store)

In my case, a boolean property called `showSidebar` which is only true if several other conditions are met - as a simplified example: `loggedIn === true` and `userProjects.length > 0`.

The logic is fine, e.g.

```
const showSidebar = loggedIn && userProjects.length > 0;
```

...but I use this in lots of components, and every time I have to import all of the dependent properties and include the conditional logic.

**How can I avoid needless duplication of logic and imported props?**

I was thinking the best way may be to write my own `useShowSidebar` hook, which would look something like the following:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const useShowSidebar = () => {
  const loggedIn = useSelector((models) => models.model.loggedIn);
  const userProjects = useSelector((models) => models.model.userProjects);
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowSidebar(loggedIn && userProjects.length > 0);
  }, [loggedIn, userProjects]);

  return showSidebar;
};

export default useShowSidebar;
```

Would this be a sensible and efficient way to achieve this without any issues? Or is there a better way? I assume this must be a common scenario.

I feel like there should be a way to have the property `showSidebar` in the global store itself as a property that is dependent upon other properties, and just import this one property into my components (using either `mapStateToProps` or the more modern `useSelector` hook, but I can't figure out if this is possible.

Comment: A "variable that is based on multiple redux props" is simply a selector and you have a text book example here. All you need is one function that computes the boolean value. You import it where you need it and pass it to `useSelector`.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you should accept it. Helps others find their answer, and you'll get some rep too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `useState` causes an unneccessary rerender. Just write it all as one selector.

```js
const useShowSidebar = () => {
  const showSidebar = useSelector((state) => 
    state.model.loggedIn && state.model.userProjects.length > 0
  );

  return showSidebar;
};
```

Or move it into a selector function and use that in your components:

```js
const selectShowSidebar = (state) => 
    state.model.loggedIn && state.model.userProjects.length > 0;

// in your component:
const showSidebar = useSelector(selectShowSidebar)
```